# Python3 Building a Pip Package 'setuptools is not defined'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pypi

I have configured my files according to the PyPi documentation for building a pip package and it worked once to build when I was creating my test server package. I made a couple of changes and am now trying to build again, but it is failing with the following error

```
Found existing installation: setuptools 44.0.0
Uninstalling setuptools-44.0.0:
  Successfully uninstalled setuptools-44.0.0
Collecting setuptools>=42
  Using cached setuptools-57.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed setuptools-57.4.0 wheel-0.36.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 331, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 284, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return hook(config_settings)
  File "/tmp/build-env-s1i_b_fr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 159, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
  File "/tmp/build-env-s1i_b_fr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 135, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-s1i_b_fr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="ontology_processing"),
NameError: name 'setuptools' is not defined

ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
```

I already have setup tools in both my pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

and included it in my setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name="ontology_processing",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="Climate Mind ontology processing code.",
    author="ClimateMind",
    author_email="omitted@omitted.com",
    url="https://github.com/ClimateMind/climatemind-ontology-processing",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="ontology_processing"),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
)
```

I've tried changing the versions of setuptools, but nothing has worked so far. I don't understand why this worked once, but is no longer working. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I screwed up.

At the top I have

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
```

but I am not importing setuptools itself

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but it was due to the inline comments I had written in the `setup.cfg` file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31341025)